# Scaling a MS SQL Server 2008 database

Tags: sql-server, scalability

Im trying to work out the best way scale my site, and i have a question on how mssql will scale.

The way the table currently is:

> cache_id - int - identifier
>   cache_name - nvchar 256 - Used for lookup along with event_id
>   cache_event_id - int - Basicly a way of grouping
>  
>   cache_creation_date - datetime
>   cache_data  - varbinary(MAX) - Data size will be from 2k to 5k

The data stored is a byte array, thats basically a cached instance (compressed) of a page on my site.

The different ways i see storing i see are:
1) 1 large table, it would contain tens millions of records and easily  become several gigabytes in size.
2) Multiple tables to contain the data above, meaning each table would 200k to a million records.

The data will be used from this table to show web pages, so anything over 200ms to get a record is bad in my eyes ( I know some ppl think 1-2 seconds page load is ok, but i think thats slow and want to do my best to keep it lower).

**So it boils down to, what is it that slows down the SQL server?**
Is it the size of the table ( disk space )
Is the the number of rows
At what point does it stop becoming cost effective to use multiple database servers?


If its close to impossible to predict these things, il accept that as a reply to. Im not a DBA, and im basically trying to design my DB so i dont have to redesign it later when its it contains huge amount of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
So it boils down to, what is it that slows down the SQL server?
Is it the size of the table ( disk space )
Is the the number of rows
At what point does it stop becoming cost effective to use multiple 
       database servers?
```

This is all a 'rule of thumb' view;
Load (and therefore to a considerable extent performance) of a DB is largely a factor of 2 issues data volumes and transaction load, with IMHO the second generally being more relevant.

With regards the data volume one can hold many gigabytes of data and get acceptable access times by way of Normalising, Indexing, Partitioning, Fast IO systems, appropriate buffer cache sizes, etc.  Many of these, e.g. Normalisation are the issues that one considers at DB design time, others during system tuning, e.g. additional/less indexes, buffer cache size.

The transactional load is largely a factor of code design and total number of users.  Code design includes factors like getting transaction size right (small and fast is the general goal, but like most things it is possible to take it to far and have transactions that are too small to retain integrity or so small as to in itself add load).

When scaling I advise first scale up (bigger, faster server) then out (multiple servers).  The admin issues of a multiple server instance are significant and I suggest only worth considering for a site with OS, Network and DBA skills and processes to match.

Answer (score 1):

Normalize and index.

How, we can't tell you, because you haven't told use what your table is trying to model or how you're trying to use it.

1 million rows is not at all uncommon. Again, we can't tell you much in the absence of context only you can, but don't, provide.

Comment: Yea, i forgot to say the data is being taken out and used to show a web page. I edited the original question to make that more clear

Answer (score 1):

The only possible answer is to set it up, and be prepared for a long iterative process of learning things only you will know because only you will live in your domain. Any technical advice you see here will be naive and insufficiently informed until you have some practical experience to share.

Test every single one of your guesses, compare the results, and see what works. And keep looking for more testable ideas. (And don't be afraid to back out changes that end up not helping. It's a basic requirement to have any hope of sustained simplicity.)

And embrace the fact that your database design will evolve. It's not as fearsome as your comment suggests you think it is. It's much easier to change a database than the software that goes around it.